# What is the best way to separate demo- / production-code in services so that a smooth switch can be made between these?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, backend

I need help understanding what the best way to separate demo code and production code in a Service class.

I use Dependency Injection to initialize a service class for a Certificate. The certificate is different for demo & publish.

Interface of CertService:

```
public interface ICertService
{
    X509Certificate2 GetCertificate();
}
```

Production: **CertService**:

```
public class CertService : ICertService
{
    protected TokenCredential keyvaultCredential;
    protected X509Certificate2Collection collection;
    protected SecretClient client;
    protected Uri urlKeyVault;
    protected string vaultName;

    ///<summary>Initializes all properties needed to get expected default certificate</summary>
    public CertService()
    {
        this.keyvaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        this.urlKeyVault = new Uri("<removed>");
        this.vaultName = "<removed>";
        this.client = new SecretClient(urlKeyVault, credential: keyvaultCredential);

        this.collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    }

    public CertService(X509Certificate2Collection collection, TokenCredential keyvaultCredential, SecretClient client, string vaultName, Uri urlKeyVault)
    {
        this.vaultName = vaultName;
        this.urlKeyVault = urlKeyVault;
        this.keyvaultCredential = keyvaultCredential;
        this.collection = collection;
        this.client = client;
    }

    public virtual X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        if (!collection.Any())
        {
            var cert = client.GetSecret(vaultName);
            var pfx = Convert.FromBase64String(cert.Value.Value);

            collection.Import(pfx);
        }

        return collection.Single();
    }
}
```

Demo **CertServiceDemo**:

```
public class CertServiceDemo : CertService
{
    public const string LOCALPATH_TEST_CERTIFICATE = @"removed.p12";

    public CertServiceDemo() : base(new X509Certificate2Collection(), null, null, null, null)
    {

    }

    public override X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        if (!this.collection.Any())
        {
            this.collection.Import(LOCALPATH_TEST_CERTIFICATE, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        }

        return this.collection.Single();
    }
}
```

I've done something like this in my Startup to make it easier for the demo app to work without having to make alot of changes when in production.

```
if (_environment.IsDevelopment()) // .vscode > launch.json > env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICertService, CertServiceDemo>();
}
else
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICertService, CertService>();
}
```

Any best practice for this? Thankyou!

Comment: You should not check IsDevelopment for a particular registration. I recommend to configure two separate service containers, one for each environment. That's all you got to do. The IoC container will take care of the rest.

Comment: @BionicCode Do i understand you if i say that i should create methods that implement Demo, Production & common services and do the IsDevelopment check to separate these types of services? Basically like i've already done but extend IServiceCollection via a static class where i put all the different services? In other words, your comment is more about keeping the code clean. Is the basics correct tho?

Comment: I have added an answer to provide an example to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure separate service containers, one for each environment.
By creating individual startup entry points you can even encapsulate other environment specific configurations to enable graceful branching.

The general pattern could be like as follows:

```cs
public static Main()
{
  if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
    ConfigureDevelopmentEnvironmentServices();
  }
  else
  {
    ConfigureProductionEnvironmentServices();
  }
}

private void ConfigureDevelopmentEnvironmentServices()
{
  var services = new ServiceCollection();
}

private void ConfigureProductionEnvironmentServices()
{
  var services = new ServiceCollection();
}
```

In an ASP.NET application you would branch from your entry point (Program.cs) as follows:

**Program.cs**

```cs
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    bool isDevelopment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT").Equals("Development", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    if (isDevelopment)    
    {
      BuildDevelopmentEnvironmentWebHost(args).Run();
    }
    else
    {
      BuildProductionEnvironmentWebHost(args).Run();
    }      
  }

  public static IWebHost BuildProductionEnvironmentWebHost(string[] args)
  {
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseStartup<ProductionEnvironmentStartup>()
      .Build();
  }

  public static IWebHost BuildDevelopmentEnvironmentWebHost(string[] args)
  {
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseStartup<DevelopmentEnvironmentStartup>()
      .Build();
  }
}
```

**ProductionEnvironmentStartup.cs**

```cs
public class ProductionEnvironmentStartup
{
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
      await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello Production World!");
    });
  }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddSingleton<ICertService, CertService>();
  }
}
```

**DevelopmentEnvironmentStartup.cs**

```cs
public class DevelopmentEnvironmentStartup
{
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
      await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello Demo World!");
    });
  }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddSingleton<ICertService, CertServiceDemo>();
  }
}
```